# FTP passive mode connection failed temporarily

Tags: windows, batch, ftp, iis

I upload image files of around 500 daily FTP connections from a batch program, but the connection did not go well temporarily.

I would like to ask you a hint about the cause.

Details:

I run it from midnight to early morning to upload images a batch program every day.
One day I couldn't upload some files for about two hours from 0:50 to 2:50. 
After that it worked well.
When the upload failed, the following IIS logs were output in large quantities.

> 00:51:30 ****** *****  ****** 21 PASV - 227 0 0 cc******07
>
> 00:51:30 ****** *****  ****** 21 PASV - 227 0 0 cc******07
>
> 00:51:30 ****** *****  ****** 53885 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 cc******07
>
> 00:51:30 ****** *****  ****** 53885 DataChannelClosed - - 32 3 cc******07
>
> 00:51:30 ****** *****  ****** 21 STOR 2******35.jpg 550 32 3 cc******07 /******/2******35.jpg
>
> 00:56:02 ****** *****  ****** 21 STOR 2******35.jpg 425 1236 50 f7******95 /******/2******35.jpg

IIS Log shows similar text many times.
The second connection, at 00:56:02, might have been an active mode connection since 425 was output.

Environment:

Windows2008 Server R2 
IIS 7.5

Remarks:

This batch program has been operating in the same environment for several years ant it have worked well, so this is the first phenomenon.

We do not make any changes to the program or the server environment.
Now, it works well without any changing for program and environment.
When Ftp connection failed, there were no other programs running something cost high load on memory or CPU included the Program or OS Update.

No error occurred around it happened.
The server machine had enough disk space.

This is the description of the situation. If possible we want to understand the cause, so you could give me some hints, it would be helpful for us.